# Python Pandas to_datetime AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv consisting of 6 columns, the first has a particular date formatting, so I need to transform it into US format YYYY-mm-dd

after reading the contents of the CSV file I proceed with the modification of the 'date' column but I keep getting the following error

**CSV**

```
Gmt time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
01.01.2021 00:00:00.000,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,0
01.01.2021 01:00:00.000,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,0
01.01.2021 02:00:00.000,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,0
01.01.2021 03:00:00.000,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,0
01.01.2021 04:00:00.000,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,1.22174,0
```

**PYTHON**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('history/EURUSDhours.csv')
df.columns = [['date','open','high','low','close','volume']]
df.date= pd.to_datetime((df.date),format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(df.head)
```

**DTYPES**

```
date       object
open      float64
high      float64
low       float64
close     float64
volume      int64
dtype: object
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eurusd.py", line 5, in <module>
    df.date= pd.to_datetime((df.date),format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 808, in to_datetime
    result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors, tz)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 899, in _assemble_from_unit_mappings
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 899, in <dictcomp>
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 894, in f
    if value.lower() in _unit_map:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: `df.columns = [['date','open','high','low','close','volume']]` will create tuple column, remove the nesting to have string column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue was passing `list of list of elements to df.columns`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('history/EURUSDhours.csv')
df.columns = ['date','open','high','low','close','volume']
df.date= pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
df
```

**Output**

```
    date    open    high    low close   volume
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 0
1   2021-01-01 01:00:00 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 0
2   2021-01-01 02:00:00 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 0
3   2021-01-01 03:00:00 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 0
4   2021-01-01 04:00:00 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 1.22174 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Assign your column names with a 1-dimension array

```
df.columns = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
```

---

You can also let [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) do all

- `header` to not use file header
- `names` to give the new col names
- `parse_dates` to specify which col parse to date
- `infer_datetime_dates` may fasten date parsing

```
df = pd.read_csv('file123.txt', header=0, 
                 names=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'],
                 parse_dates=['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```